# IdentityServer4 cookie validation

Tags: angular, identityserver4

I build an Angular 4 site that send authentication details (username/password) to IdentityServer4 and successfully receive a token back (grant type = resource owner password).

Now I want to redirect user to another (different) ASP Core MVC site from my Angular 4 site.
 *Somehow I can not find a way to set up 'headers' in redirection to pass token as a Authorization: Bearer xxx*.

I set up cookie in Angular site and then just `window.location.href = 'www.example.com/another_site`

On MVC site I configure in Startup.cs:

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
{
        ...
        ...

        app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions()
        {
            AuthenticationScheme = "Cookies_Authentication",
            AutomaticAuthenticate = true,
            AutomaticChallenge = true
        });

        app.UseIdentityServerAuthentication(new IdentityServerAuthenticationOptions
        {
            Authority = "http://my_identityserver4_address:49950",
            RequireHttpsMetadata = false,
            AuthenticationScheme = "Cookies_Authentication",

            ApiName = "Protected_Api.get",
            AutomaticAuthenticate = true,
            AutomaticChallenge = true
        });
}
```

but I'm still receiving 401 Unauthorized response from MVC site. What I'm doing wrong ?

May be IdentityServer looking for special cookie name ? I'm setting it in Angular as:

`cookieService.setItem('access_token', 'eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsImtpZCI6ImFlOWEyMzNhZDczOTUwNWI4YjJkZGE0NTNiMDE........)`

Answer (score 1):

I think you might find your answer [here](https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4.Samples/tree/release/Clients/src/MvcImplicit) just see how mvc app receiving the token from identity server and just do same thing when redirecting from your angular app. And you need to play around with this [example](https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4.Samples/tree/release/Quickstarts/3_ImplicitFlowAuthentication/src).

UPDATE: @jasper yes you right you need to check the docks on OAuth  OPenID thing at https://identityserver4.readthedocs.io also checkout their blog at http://leastprivilege.com

Comment: I guess your answer was the closest one - I need to learn more about [OAuth and OpenID Connect](https://identityserver4.readthedocs.io/en/release/quickstarts/3_interactive_login.html) but direction is to use OpneID Connect for cookie authentication and not Bearer headers.

Answer (score 0):

If this another MVC app is defined as another client on the auth server you don't have to set up anything else except configuring the cookie and authentication middleware in the startup class, just the way you are doing already.

Basically, If user has logged in from App A and open another App B it doesn't need to re-login as it will be able to validate the existing cookies on the browser. It will just needs to authenticate itself which it will do through back channel.

Comment: What do you mean by saying: ...  It will just needs to authenticate itself ...  ?

Comment: i meant the user is already authorized, as cookies will validate if user logs in App A and opens App B, but the user is not authenticated on that App B which it will do through back channel as it already got auth code. Identity server gives you Single sign on, user doesn't have to re-login on each app. But access token would be different for different apps.